# Phonegap popup showing when app is re-opened

Tags: cordova, popup, alert

I am creating an iOS Phonegap application. In which I am using a the script from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html

```
// Show a custom alert

function showAlert() {
    navigator.notification.alert(
      "Do you really want to delete this item?",  // message
        alertDismissed,         // callback
        "Delete",            // title
        "Ok, Cancel"                  // buttonName
    );
}

 // alert dialog dismissed
         function alertDismissed() {
 //      alert("Test this");// write your necessary code here
}
```

I have called the .js files in my html

The issue which I have is quite strange. I click on the button to see the popup in my app and nothing happens. But if I close and reopen the app I see the popup, which I should had seen before!

Can someone help!

Comment: is this code for an android device?